# Convert time stamp to date in LoadRunner

Tags: performance-testing

I have to correlate a date in my script, but from response I'm getting time stamp for that particular date, is there any way in LoadRunner I can convert time stamp to a date ? Please reply with your valuable suggestions.
Please let me know in case of any confusion.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/c

Comment: @JamesPulley Hi James can you please recommend me from where I can get the best study material for LoadRunner certification.

Comment: The HP Tutorial, the HP provided study guide for your exam, the Books and your experience.  The statement of ethics at the beginning of the exam prevents you from using any other materials